# gsub not replacing all expected matches in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Let's say I have the string `x <- "AbC"` and I want to put an ampersand in between each letter. I would have assumed I could just do `gsub("([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])", "\\1 & \\2", x)`, but that produces "A & bC". Why doesn't `gsub` recognize the second set of letters that match the regex? It's not like `gsub` only replaces the first match found. If I have `x <- "AbC DE"` and run the same command, I get "A & bC D & E".

What am I missing in terms of how `gsub` is doing it's replacement? I would have expected outputs of "A & b & C" and "A & b & C D & E" from the two inputs above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because if a character present in one match, regex engine won't match the same character again. That is, it won't do overlapping matches.. Use lookaround to overcome this..

```
gsub("([a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z])", "\\1 & ", x, perl=T)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iP7yS1/1)

Comment: Perfectly explained. Thanks!